# How to declare a class instance as a constant in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, constants

I need to implement this:

```
static class MyStaticClass
{
    public const TimeSpan theTime = new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0);
    public static bool IsTooLate(DateTime dt)
    {
        return dt.TimeOfDay >= theTime;
    }
}
```

`theTime` is a constant (seriously :-), like `π` is, in my case it'd be pointless to read it from settings, for example. And I'd like it to be initialized once and never changed.

But C# doesn't seem to allow a constant to be initialized by a function (which a constructor is). How to overcome this?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Using `readonly` instead of `const` can be initialized and not modified after that. Is that what you're looking for?

Code example:

```
static class MyStaticClass
{
    static readonly TimeSpan theTime;

    static MyStaticClass()
    {
        theTime = new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I use this in my own code, but my anal retentive personality knows that every time I do this there is a long living object in memory of my application. I have a long running application that already uses a too much memory, and it just bothers me.  I wish there was a TimeSpan literal that would just get compiled in to my code.  The alternative is to have an const int, converting my TimeSpan value to miliseconds... but math.

Comment: Readonly isn't a correct analog to const. Instead you'd want to use static readonly, as mentioned in James's answer below.

Comment: @ashelvey I found this page while looking for a constant way to do this like the OP. In my case readonly does not work nor does static. I want to use it inside an attribute on a class property - which means I need a constant. (I did not down vote you because this isn't likely possible, but this is one possible reason you got some.)

Comment: readonly static doesn't work with switch cases and default parameters. We still need const.

Answer (score 48):

Constants have to be compile time constant, and the compiler can't evaluate your constructor at compile time.  Use [`readonly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx) and a [`static` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx).

```
static class MyStaticClass
{
  static MyStaticClass()
  {
     theTime = new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0);
  }

  public static readonly TimeSpan theTime;
  public static bool IsTooLate(DateTime dt)
  {
    return dt.TimeOfDay >= theTime;
  }
}
```

In general I prefer to initialise in the constructor rather than by direct assignment as you have control over the order of initialisation.

Comment: `theTime`  should be `static` as well. So that there's only one, and so that the above example compiles.

Comment: Why a constructor? Just describing a member as public static readonly TimeSpan theTime  = new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0) seems to work (no compilation errors at least).

Comment: @pickypg - sorry my mistake - fixed.  @Ivan - I added a comment on that.  I personally dislike direct initialisation as you need to search a class to find out where things are initialised.  Putting initialisation always in the constructor is consistent and you can easily see what the initial state of a class is.  You also have direct control over the order in which initialisation takes place.  In a trivial static class case there probably isn't much difference.  But good practice is good practice - especially in the edge cases.

Comment: The greatest benefit to using a ctor for member initialization is that you get the opportunity to catch and handle exceptions in the context that they are raised.

Answer (score 13):

C#'s `const` does not have the same meaning as C++'s `const`. In C#, `const` is used to essentially define aliases to literals (and can therefore only be initialized with literals). `readonly` is closer to what you want, but keep in mind that it only affects the assignment operator (the object isn't really constant unless its class has immutable semantics).

Comment: Worth mentioning here that `static readonly` fields **can** be changed via reflection, while `const` **cannot**.

Answer (score 9):

From [this link](http://en.csharp-online.net/const,_static_and_readonly):

> Constants must be a value type (sbyte,
>   byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long,
>   ulong, char, float, double, decimal,
>   or bool), an enumeration, a string
>   literal, or a reference to null.

If you want to create an object, it must be done so as `static readonly`:

```
static class MyStaticClass
{
  public static readonly TimeSpan theTime = new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0);
  public static bool IsTooLate(DateTime dt)
  {
    return dt.TimeOfDay >= theTime;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
public static readonly TimeSpan theTime = new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Constant represents a static member whose value can never change. This means that a constant value is defined in compile time.

With the statement:

```
    public const TimeSpan theTime = new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0);
```

Are violated two axioms of constant fields:

- **Only the C# built-in types (excluding System.Object) may be declared as const.**
- **Iniatialization value must be evaluated in compile time**

In the question is used the TimeSpan type, which is not **built-in (predefined)** Type. This means that the csc.exe compiler cannot recognize it.
If you use a built-in C# type (e.g. String) and you want to initialize the constant member with a compile time value, you still get an error:
e.g.

```
 public const string MyNumber = SetMyString();
 private string SetMyString()
 {
  return "test";
 }
```

Solving the problem you can declare a member with:

```
static readonly
```

modifier if you want to declare a field only once in runtime:

```
public static readonly string MyNumber = SetMyString();
private static string SetMyString()
{
 return "test";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[You can use the readonly keyword](https://web.archive.org/web/20150519205233/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx):

> When a field declaration includes a readonly modifier, assignments to
> the fields introduced by the declaration can only occur as part of the
> declaration or in a constructor in the same class.

Example (copied from the linked MSDN page):

```
class Age
{
    readonly int _year;
    Age(int year)
    {
        _year = year;
    }
    void ChangeYear()
    {
        //_year = 1967; // Compile error if uncommented.
    }
}
```